# how to discard saved session on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, session, logout

I installed Xubuntu and used one of shutdown functions when shutdown it.

It looks as follow image:

[image: logout]

I leaved tick and now I always login at this session.

But I want to leave this session and login as typical.

- ***How to discard this session, and login without saved session?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xubuntu stores your session information in `~/.cache/sessions`. If you want to start with a clean slate, you need to remove the information present in that folder.

To do so:

- Log out of Xubuntu.
- While at the login screen, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open a console. (You may need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once to get the login prompt.) Enter your usual username and password.
- Create a temporary folder, `Backup`, on your Desktop. Return to your home folder. From there, issue the following command to recursively copy the contents of `~/.cache/sessions` to your desktop (as a safety measure):

  - `mkdir ~/Desktop/Backup`
  - `cp -r ~/.cache/sessions/* ~/Desktop/Backup`
- Delete the contents of the `sessions` subfolder:

  - `rm -rf ~/.cache/sessions/*`
- Close the console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
- You'll see the usual login screen again. Now, when you login, you'll have a clean slate.

Note that [there is a GUI method available](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/preferences) but some people find it doesn't work as reliably as the console route.

Comment: can I do it when login as typical? Coz console didn't display after `Cntr + Alt + F1`

Comment: try F2 instead of F1

Comment: You should not try when logged in as normal because the session files will be in use. By logging out of the Xubuntu/Xfce session, these files are not in use (and can be accessed by the virtual terminal).

Answer (score 0):

You should erase old sessions and make session folder read-only:

`$ rm .cache/session/*
$ chmod -w .cache/session`

See my full answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/469808/27057

Comment: I want to delete saved one. How to achieve this?