# Unable to disable Session restore on xubuntu 12.04

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, restore, session

I am using Xubuntu 12.04 with the xfce 4.10 ppa, and since updating xfce I can not disable the automatic session restore.

I have disabled the relevant options in 'Session and Startup', but it makes no differences and all my windows are still restored after login.

If I remove the content of `.cache/sessions` it works for the next reboot but after that the session will be restored again.

I thought about writing a script to delete it at startup, but I was wondering if there were any proper fixes to this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you have a look at `apps->gnome-session->options` in gconf-editor whether its enabled there?

Comment: not sure what you mean ? I am using xfce, where is this gnome-session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no other suggestions, here is a quick fix for anyone who comes across this thread :

```
emacs _path_/startup.sh
```

write in the file

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf /home/_name_/.cache/sessions/*
```

make it executable

```
chmod +x _path_/startup.sh
```

go under 'Session and Startup' and add `_path_/startup.sh` to the applications automatically executed when xfce opens.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you have stumbled on a bug related to the `Action Buttons`. For a discussion of a very similar issue reported recently see:

- [How to permanently disable the "save session" feature in Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427842/permanently-delete-the-feature-save-session-xubuntu-13-10/427962#427962)