# Thunar settings keep reverting

Tags: thunar

I set my thunar settings to view as list, show hidden files etc.

Those settings are lost on a reboot.

How do I repair that?

Comment: It looks very strange. Many times you write your question here and on [Ubuntu MATE community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/thunar-settings-keep-reverting/17404). Both are Ubuntu, this in not the problem. But why you do not want to use [Caja](https://mate-desktop.org/)? Just curious. About settings - do you have any problems with permissions? If unsure run `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~` and test again.

Comment: Thunar has more features, custom actions, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I have *Thunar 1.6.15* installed on a Lubuntu 18.04 system.

[image: Thunar --- View Settings]

The image shows the *View* dropdown with the various options. The *Show Hidden Files* and *View as Detailed List* settings behave as expected.

The changes should be reflected in *~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/thunar.xml*.

Here are the contents of *thunar.xml* with the *Show Hidden Files* and *View as Detailed List* settings **active**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<channel name="thunar" version="1.0">
  <property name="last-view" type="string" value="ThunarDetailsView"/>
  <property name="last-icon-view-zoom-level" type="string" value="THUNAR_ZOOM_LEVEL_NORMAL"/>
  <property name="last-window-maximized" type="bool" value="true"/>
  <property name="last-details-view-zoom-level" type="string" value="THUNAR_ZOOM_LEVEL_SMALLER"/>
  <property name="last-details-view-column-widths" type="string" value="50,188,50,50,641,50,50,83,174"/>
  <property name="last-show-hidden" type="bool" value="true"/>
  <property name="last-separator-position" type="int" value="170"/>
  <property name="misc-single-click" type="bool" value="false"/>
</channel>
```

Here are the contents of *thunar.xml* with the *Show Hidden Files* and *View as Detailed List* settings **turned off**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<channel name="thunar" version="1.0">
  <property name="last-view" type="string" value="ThunarCompactView"/>
  <property name="last-icon-view-zoom-level" type="string" value="THUNAR_ZOOM_LEVEL_NORMAL"/>
  <property name="last-window-maximized" type="bool" value="true"/>
  <property name="last-details-view-zoom-level" type="string" value="THUNAR_ZOOM_LEVEL_SMALLER"/>
  <property name="last-details-view-column-widths" type="string" value="50,188,50,50,654,50,50,83,174"/>
  <property name="last-show-hidden" type="bool" value="false"/>
  <property name="last-separator-position" type="int" value="170"/>
  <property name="misc-single-click" type="bool" value="false"/>
</channel>
```

Of note are the values of `property name="last-show-hidden"` and `property name="last-view"`.

Could it be, though I can't say why, that your *~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/thunar.xml* is damaged or that it doesn't have the appropriate permissions or that Thunar cannot, for whatever reason, write changes to this file?

In my case, the permissions look like this:

```
dkb@dkb:~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 dkb dkb 847 Jul 28 07:26 thunar.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 dkb dkb 429 May  9 06:16 xfce4-power-manager.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 dkb dkb 212 May  9 06:16 xfce4-session.xml
dkb@dkb:~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml$
```

Comment: Good effort to write out details. Matches my dystem

Comment: In your question you didn't specify that changes were lost **after** a reboot. If that is the case, see if https://askubuntu.com/a/427962/248158 helps.

Comment: I found the problem. /home/andy/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/ was set to root as owner. I changed owner to myself.